# Spark: count two fields together

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to count some parameters with Spark. I used the word count example.
In this example, we can count a word but I wonder how I can count two fields at the same time.

Here is what I want to do:

**Input files**

```
{
    "redundancy":1,
    "deviceID":"dv1"
}
{
    "redundancy":1,
    "deviceID":"dv2"
}
{
    "redundancy":2,
    "deviceID":"dv1"
}
{
    "redundancy":1,
    "deviceID":"dv1"
}
{
    "redundancy":2,
    "deviceID":"dv5"
}
```

**Output files**

```
{
    "redundancy":1,
    "count":3,
    "nbDevice":2
}
{
    "redundancy":2,
    "count":2,
    "nbDevice":2
}
```

I wonder if there is already an example of this use case or if you have any documentation or links, i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pairs as keys.

The solution can look like:

```
rdd.map(record => (record.firstField, record.secondField) -> 1)
   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```